# Do I need to run /usr/libexec/makewhatis, to use whatis

Tags: command-line

Please am still new to unix. Am learning at the moment. Am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS on a virtual machine(oracle). I want to try the command 'whatis', but the book am reading says this:-

> Before running whatis the first time on your system — particularly if you’re running a standalone machine using FreeBSD, Linux, or Darwin — you’ll want to run the makewhatis at /usr/ libexec/ makewhatis, which creates the whatis database by scanning the command names from the existing manpages.

I tried running `/usr/libexec/makewhatis`, I got this

```
bash: /usr/libexec/makewhatis: no such file or directory
```

I tried doing `sudo apt install makewhatis`, I got this, after reading package lists, building dependency tree, reading state information

```
E: Unable to locate package makewhatis
```

When I did `whatis cat` though, I got the result I was expecting. Please I just want to know if I don't need to run `/usr/libexec/makewhatis`, on my system, to use whatis the first time, and everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/libexec` doesn't exist on Ubuntu by default. Hence the error is proper. Your book might be slightly outdated. To quote [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1329):

> Enter makewhatis. This command creates the whatis database files used by both apropos and whatis. They are located in each ../man directory and catalog the manual files in each of the individual cat? and man? subdirectories.

If you read the manual for `whatis` you'll see that it's not necessary to be done anymore on modern systems(emphasis added):

> index  databases are used during the search, and are **updated by the mandb program**.  Depending on your installation, this may be run by a periodic cron job, or may need to be run manually after new manual pages  have  been installed.

Comment: Cheers mate. Understood

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 16.04 it is not necessary to execute the

`/usr/libexec/makewhatis`

command, only execute the command

`whatis cat`

whatis cat has the same result as man -f cat

Comment: Cheers mate. Do you mind if I ask why not so, for Ubuntu 16.04